# Why MAX() will not pick respective maximum value row details?

Tags: mysql, sql

**Employee**

```
**|employeeId|  name    |salary |address|**
---------------------------------------------
|1          |John   |45000  |San Fransisco|
|2          |Michel |100000 |Attil|
```

If I want to select Max salaried person details in Employee table, currently I had to write 2 queries, out of which one is inner.

**Query 1)**

```
Select *
From Employee 
Where salary = (Select MAX(salary) From Employee)
```

**Query 2)**

```
Select MAX(salary), employeeId
From Employee
```

**Result:**

```
**|MAX(salary)|      employeeId|**
-------------------------------
|100000|             1|
```

If MySQL MAX function designed such a way to select max salary and max salaried employee id in one shot, (as currently MAX will not guarantee this) I would have written very thin queries :( Because most of the requirements will not just stop at finding maximum of an entity property, they would always show interest in all properties of MAX entity. Like here in our case, I just don’t want to find what is maximum salary. I am actually interested in that employee details.

1. Why MySQL (MAX)is not doing this?
2. If we talk about Single responsibility of MAX, currently it’s doing fine and enough. But why are they allowing to select some property after doing MAX(), which is actually confusing me?. Because how can I expect that selected results could be any random value, which does not belong to MAX ly selected entity.(As in the above **[Query 2] result**, **employeeId 1** is no way related to **Max salary 100000**)
3. Rather than giving some random result, what is the harm to give results that are the actual properties of MAX ly selected entity? (As it could be **100000 as max salary** and **2 as employeeId**)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I absolutely love why questions.. they make me think.

**Why MySQL (MAX)is not doing this?**
max is a scalar value it will return 1 and only 1 result per grouping. If you had multiple records being returned because of employeID is being returned, the result would no longer be scaler.  Say if multiple employees had the same salary

**If we talk about Single responsibility of MAX, currently it’s doing fine and enough. But why are they allowing to select some property after doing MAX(), which is actually confusing me?. Because how can I expect that selected results could be any random value, which does not belong to MAX ly selected entity.(As in the above [Query 2] result, employeeId 1 is no way related to Max salary 100000)**

It likely has to do with order of operations in the engine.  The from clause, the where clause the group by ... having... then the select orderby.  Since the group by happens before the values are selected, having different values added to the from because they "Tie" with the max would make the group by inaccurate.  cardinality  between records would get messed up and math done on subsequent queries would become inaccurate.

**Rather than giving some random result, what is the harm to give results that are the actual properties of MAX ly selected entity? (As it could be 100000 as max salary and 2 as employeeId)**

So in my belief, due to order of SQL operations, and the nature of max being a scaler value per grouping, and the need to group by to behave and to maintain carnality; all max can do is return a single value per grouping.  all other attribute data must be garnered by subsequent queries.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a subquery for this -- if you want one row:

```
select *
from Employee 
order by salary desc
limit 1;
```

This query:

```
Select MAX(salary), employeeId
From Employee;
```

is malformed.  Happily, the more recent versions of MySQL will generate an error for this query (as do almost all other databases).  `MAX()` is an aggregation function.  This query is better interpreted as:

```
Select MAX(salary), ANY(employeeId)
From Employee;
```

Alas, `ANY()` is not a recognized aggregation function.  The point is that the `salary` is the maximum salary.  The `employeeId` is an arbitrary employee id from some row in the table.

You seem to be confused about the role of different clauses in a SQL query.  The `SELECT` clause specifies what columns in a particular row to return.  It does not specify *which* rows to return, just which columns.

In a simple `SELECT` with no `JOIN` or `GROUP BY`, the `WHERE` clause determines the rows being returned.  The `WHERE` clause only knows about a particular row, so it it not privy to the maximum value.  That is why an additional subquery is needed.

Comment: I understand the precedence of those clauses and scope of them in a table of data also. But still, as an end user and SQL developer, it would be great if the result gives 100000 and 2 rather than 1 as employeeId. What do you think?

Comment: @SaikumarVantaku . . . Absolutely not.  You don't seem to understand what `SELECT` clauses do and what other clauses do.